# Set focus to a uifigure window

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

How can I set focus to a `uifigure` after the focus is switched out to a different figure?

For `uicontrol`, it is possible with set focus on one of its child elements. For example:

```
% create a new uicontrol text label
h = uicontrol('style','text','string','This is my figure');
% create a figure to switch the focus
figure;
% switch back
uicontrol(h)
```

However, for `uifigure`, adopting a similar code only creates a new `uifigure`.

Some code for you to try:

```
% create a new uifigure
h = uifigure('Name','This is my figure');
% create a new uilabel as a child of uifigure
lh = uilabel(h)
% create a figure to switch the focus
figure;
% this creates a new uifigure then switch back
uifigure(h)
% this creates an error as the first input argument must be a valid parent for uilabel
uilabel(lh)
```

Any idea, insight or contribution is appreciated.

Note your Matlab version should be at least 2016a, since this is when `uifigure` is introduced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is yet another one of the casualties of The MathWorks' bizarre strategy of releasing a new UI framework before it actually has any features. Granted, the new framework shows a lot of promise, but it still [lags far behind](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/graphics-support-in-app-designer.html) the older graphics system in terms of functionality.

Rant aside, there's a quick workaround that tests fine in R2017a: toggle the visibility of the `uifigure`, which brings it to the fore. Here's a basic example:

```
function uifigurepop(uifigurehandle)
drawnow;
uifigurehandle.Visible = 'off';
uifigurehandle.Visible = 'on';
end
```

Which, if we bring this into the sample code:

```
% create a new uifigure
h = uifigure('Name','This is my figure');
% create a new uilabel as a child of uifigure
lh = uilabel(h)
% create a figure to switch the focus
figure;
% this creates a new uifigure then switch back
uifigure()
uifigurepop(h);
```

Your figure is now rendered topmost on the screen.

Comment: but there is no way to set the initial cursor focus on an element of the uifigure?  e.g., uieditfield

Comment: @BrianD this is possible too, take a look in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62551221/3372061).